# Process data after the kv file is loaded

Tags: python, inheritance, kivy

### The problem

The `RefreshLabel()` method should be executed **right after the rendering** of the window

Need to be able to initialize variables or perform other operations that need to be done after the kv file has been read so I can connect to databases or other external resources. - **In other words; the user should never be able to read the words *Text NOT updated***

[image: rendered updated window of the kivy program]

---

### Simplified code

**main.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    my_label = ObjectProperty(None)

    def RefreshLabel(self):
        self.my_label.text = "Text updated"

class designApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    designApp().run()
```

**design.kv**

```
<MyGrid>
    cols:1
    size: root.width, root.height

    my_label: my_label

    Label:
        id: my_label
        text: "Text NOT updated"

    Button:
        text: "Update text"
        on_press: root.RefreshLabel()
```

Comment: Are you actually calling `RefreshLabel()` on its own? If it's a class member, it should be called on a class instance, i.e. `my_grid_object.RefreshLabel()`, if it's outside the class. Otherwise, it needs to be called inside another class function.

Comment: The only instance of MyGrid is the output of the build() function. Being an unusual way to instantiate a class, I am not sure how or where to implement the method outside the class.

I could call it from another method. But I will face the same problem with the new method.

Comment: Can you please be more specific about what exactly you want, given your code.

Comment: Sure. I need to make use of the `RefreshLabel()` method without the intervention of the **button**. -- In the original(more complex) version of my application; **labels** take the **text** from a **database**. -- I have many more widgets that need to be updated and much more logic in the `Refresh()` function. -- Executing the necessary logic without being encapsulated in a method is **not** an option

Comment: Wouldn't calling the method `RefreshLabel` from the `__init__` method of `MyGrid` do the job in particular ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `on_kv_post`:

```
class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    my_label = ObjectProperty(None)

    def on_kv_post(self, base_widget):
        self.my_label.text = "Text updated"
```